# Stuck at the first step of making a chat client using smack

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I was starting to build a chat client using java on smack and eclipse, so I started writing the following code:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;

public class A {

// Create a connection to the igniterealtime.org XMPP server.
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection("myserver.com");
    // Connect to the server
    connection.connect();
    // Most servers require you to login before performing other tasks.
    connection.login("admin2", "123");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     A a= new A();

}

}
```

But I am getting the following two errors:

```
Syntax error on token "connect", Identifier expected after this token
```

and

```
Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
```

Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

U cannot put statements ( like *connection.connect()* ) out of method body.

Try something like this:

```
public class A 
{
    public void start()
    {
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection("myserver.com");
        // Connect to the server
        connection.connect();
        // Most servers require you to login before performing other tasks.
        connection.login("admin2", "123");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        A a= new A();
        a.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you,seems like I am fumbling with the basics too here